# How to pre-populate phone in paypal checkout?

Tags: html, paypal, paypal-buttons

I am trying to pre-populate all the fields in the paypal page, but the phone is not populating.

Here is my code:

```
<INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="first_name" VALUE="John">
<INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="last_name" VALUE="Doe">
<INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="address1" VALUE="9 Elm Street">
<INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="address2" VALUE="Apt 5">
<INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="city" VALUE="Berwyn">
<INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="state" VALUE="PA">
<INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="zip" VALUE="19312">
<INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="lc" VALUE="US">
<INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="email" VALUE="buyer@domain.com">
<INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="night_phone_a" VALUE="610">
<INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="night_phone_b" VALUE="555">
<INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="night_phone_c" VALUE="1234">
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in PayPal and the PD team has been working towards a fix.